# Background won't cover whole page

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

```
    ScrollView {
        ZStack{
            NavigationView(){
                List {...}
                .toolbar {...}                    }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingProfile) {...}
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingVoortgang) {...} 
            }
        }
    }
    .background(Image("Background3")
        .resizable()
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .opacity(1))
```

// I have a NavigationView in a Stack in a ScrollView. I made the background of the scrollView my picture but it wouldn't render the whole page, only the background of the back page and not the NavigationView

Comment: you need to set .ignoresSafeArea() for the most parent view

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your issue is that content inside `NavigationView` does not have the background image you applied to scroll view.

One way to do this is to use `blendMode()` on NavigationView, try it with `.darken`, `.overlay`, `.plusDarker` or other modes to see which one you like better.

Example in your code:

```
ScrollView {
    ZStack{
        NavigationView(){
            List {...}
            .toolbar {...}                    }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingProfile) {...}
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingVoortgang) {...} 
        }
        .blendMode(.plusDarker) // <--
    }
}
.background(Image("Background3")
    .resizable()
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .opacity(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ScrollView {
    ZStack{
        NavigationView(){
            List {...}
            .toolbar {...}                    }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingProfile) {...}
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingVoortgang) {...} 
        }
    }
    .background(Image("Background3")
    .resizable()
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```